# How to create an XSLT Filter to extract all contents of an ODT (containing an XForm) to XHTML

Tags: filter, export, xslt, openoffice.org, xforms

I'm trying to use the Export feature of OpenOffice Writer to create an XHtml File from an ODT containing an XForm.

What I noticed was that the XForm Model was not getting exported. I copied the default XSL file used and I changed the "xsl:stylesheet" node's "exclude-result-prefixes" to an empty string.

The output was the same. I searched the internet for more help and came across

https://issues.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=87731

The "xsl:template" tags provided here helped in exporting the most of the content.
1. The XForm instance, model, binding etc.

However the actual controls were still missing...

I believe the trick lies in "xsl:template" tags, but have no documentation to understand how the export feature uses them.

Any ideas on this?????

Comment: It would help if you would share some exact details. Can you provide a small sample of your XHTML output? What browser (and extensions) are you using to display the XForms controls?

Comment: I am a bit new to StackOverflow... how does one attach files to posts. Should I use an external file hosting site to give you the XHTML output

or just Paste the content here....

Comment: You could insert a link, or just copy/paste it in your question with an indent of at least 1 tab or 4 spaces. Long listings will get a scrollbar of their own, so even larger listings are okay. You could also create a gist at github or use something like pastebin to link to.

Answer (score 0):

Decide which XHTML element maps to each missing XForms control, then create a `xsl:template` matching each control which includes the desired XHTML output. Here are a few examples of similar conversion stylesheets:

- [Atom2HTML](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-atomxsl/x-atomxsl.html)
- [RDF2HTML](http://rhizomik.net/redefer-services/xsl/rdf2html.xsl)(View Source)
- [XML2XHTML](http://www.linkwerk.com/pub/xml/invitation/xml2xhtml/)

[XSLTForms](http://xsltforms.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/xsltforms/releases/1.0RC/xsltforms.xsl?revision=550&content-type=text%2Fplain) is an excellent reference as well.